# Does weak convergence in $L^2$ imply convergence a.e. of a subsequence?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

The title pretty much explains it all. Let $u_n\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a sequence converging weakly in $L^2$ to some $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, that is $\int u_k v \to \int u v$ for all $v\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Does it follow that there is a subsequence $u_{n_h}$ such that $u_{n_h}(x)\to u(x)$ for a.e. $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ (with respect to the Lebesgue measure)?

Comment: No: $e^{inx}\to 0$ weakly in $L^2(0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but it does imply something that might suffice for your purposes. By the Banach-Saks Theorem, $(u_n)$ admits a subsequence $(u_{n(k)})$ whose Cesàro means
$$
{1\over N}\sum_{k=1}^N u_{n(k)}
$$
converge   in the $L^2$ norm. These means then admit a further subsequence that is a.e. convergent.

The result holds in $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$, not just $L^2$.